# How do I draw stuff under the text of a UILabel?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uibezierpath

I created a custom `UILabel` subclass that has a circle in the middle, and the label's text (which is a number) will be on top of the circle.

I initially thought of doing this using `layer.cornerRadius`, but that will not create a circle when the label's width and height are not equal.

What I mean is, for a label with width 100 and height 50, I still want a circle with radius 50 and centre at (50, 25).

Therefore, I tried to use `UIBezierPath` to draw the circle. This is what I have tried:

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    super.draw(rect)
    if bounds.height > bounds.width {
        let y = (bounds.height - bounds.width) / 2
        let path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(x: 0, y: y, width: bounds.width, height: bounds.width))
        circleColor.setFill()
        path.fill()
    } else {
        let x = (bounds.width - bounds.height) / 2
        let path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(x: x, y: 0, width: bounds.height, height: bounds.height))
        circleColor.setFill()
        path.fill()
    }
}
```

I have put `super.draw(rect)` because I thought that would draw the label's text, but when I run the app, I only see the circle and not my label text.

I am very confused because why hasn't `super.draw(rect)` drawn the label's text?

Comment: When drawing/painting, think in the context of a physical canvas, those things you paint will be covered by those things you paint/draw later

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The text is not seen because the "z-index" of `UIBezierPath`s depends on the order in which they are drawn. In other words, `UIBezierPath`s are drawn on top of each other.

`super.draw(rect)` indeed draws the text. But when you put it as the first statement, it will get drawn *first*, so everything you draw after that, goes *on top of* the text. To fix this, you should call `super.draw(rect)` last:

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    if bounds.height > bounds.width {
        let y = (bounds.height - bounds.width) / 2
        let path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(x: 0, y: y, width: bounds.width, height: bounds.width))
        circleColor.setFill()
        path.fill()
    } else {
        let x = (bounds.width - bounds.height) / 2
        let path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(x: x, y: 0, width: bounds.height, height: bounds.height))
        circleColor.setFill()
        path.fill()
    }
    super.draw(rect) // <------- here!
}
```

Alternatively, just subclass `UIView`, draw the circle in `draw(_:)`, and add a `UILabel` as a subview of that. The advantage if this approach is that it does not depend on the implementation of `super.draw(_:)`, which might change in the future,

Comment: Instead of subclassing the UILabel, why not just create a custom view with the UILabel on top, and leave the drawing code in the custom view?

Comment: @meim I want to make it using as few subviews as possible, because I don't want to add that many constraints on each of them.

Comment: With this implementation, it's possible in the future your custom drawing code is overwritten by super.draw(rect) since it's a black box inside UILabel's implementation. In the custom view implementation, if you're worried about too many constraints, you can simply set label.frame = bounds in layoutSubviews